# One to Many relationship throwing (null value in column "permission_group_id" violates not-null constraint)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

**Parent.java:**

```
@Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pgroup_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="pgroup_generator", sequenceName = "pg_seq", allocationSize=50)
    @Column(
               name = "group_id",
               unique = true,
               updatable = false,
               nullable = false
            )
    private Long id;

    
    @Column(name="group_name",unique = true)
    private String groupName;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=PermissionsEntity.class, mappedBy = "permissionGroup", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PermissionsEntity> permissions= new ArrayList<>();

public void setPermissions(List<PermissionsEntity> permissions) {
        
        this.permissions = permissions;
        for(PermissionsEntity p:permissions) {
            p.setPermissionGroup(this);
        }
    }
```

**child.java:**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="group_id",  referencedColumnName = "group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PermissionGroupEntity permissionGroup;
```

**Here is the error log:**

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "permission_group_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (11, null, 2020-11-02 10:52:34.849, null, 2020-11-02 10:52:34.849, Allow the user to create findings, create audit or workpaper findings, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

Comment: Also that `allocationSize=50` will be a problem. Let Postgres handle the sequences and IDs, and use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in your code.

Comment: tried with identity generator but still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `insertable = false` on that `permissionGroup`, it's not being inserted, leaving it null. Remove that setting to leave it the default `true`.

Comment: Changes don't work for me, still throwing the same error.